# How do I remove the PowerShell "open here" context menu?

Tags: powershell, windows-registry, context-menu

I removed PowerShell 7 preview and installed PowerShell 7.0.2. Now I have a broken context menu entry for the PowerShell 7 preview. Where in the registry can I remove this?

[image]

Comment: You are likely to find the entry under ```HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\``` in the registry editor. I am not sure what the key will be named as I have not installed PowerShell 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you uninstall it?

The Add-Remove programs, should have removed all of this? MS provides steps fro that question here:

[How to uninstall Powershell Windows 7](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/how-to-uninstall-powershell-windows-7/c7077177-294d-4aed-8307-a1a554a56ae5)

This link goes through each option as well as highlights registry locations.

See also this discussion which presents a cleanup script options for this use case.

[Remove duplicate `Open Here` context menu item upgrading to newer Preview release #8496](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/8496)

Again, make sure to review any code you get from anywhere to make sure you fully understand what it is doing, especially in destructive actions.